# Enable JsTestDriver Failed Test Messages and fix FailureException error?

Tags: javascript, exception, tdd, js-test-driver

I'm following along with [Test Driven Javascript Development](http://tddjs.com/) and just finshed setting up jstestdriver.  I'm receiving odd errors and failed test messages when running failing tests, for example:

```
TestCase("ArrayTest", {
  "test array splice should not modify array": function () {
    var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    var result = arr.splice(2, 3);
    assertEquals([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], arr);
  }
});
```

My failed test output is fairly succinct and includes an odd FailureException error:

```
F
Total 1 tests (Passed: 0; Fails: 1; Errors: 0) (3.00 ms)
  Chrome 27.0.1453.116 Mac OS: Run 1 tests (Passed: 0; Fails: 1; Errors 0) (3.00 ms)
    ArrayTest.test array splice should not modify array failed (3.00 ms):

null
com.google.jstestdriver.FailureException
    at com.google.jstestdriver.FailureCheckerAction.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.jstestdriver.ActionRunner.runActions(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.jstestdriver.JsTestDriverServer.main(Unknown Source)
```

I would like to know if it's possible to fix that failure exception, and also receive a message such as “expected [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] but was [1, 2]", as the book mentions you should receive.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sure it is possible.

There are at least two ways:

1. to write your own comparator function for arrays
2. to convert both arrays to string and compare them as a strings with assertEquals

For example:

```
assertEquals([1, 2, 3, 4, 5] + "", arr + "");
```

To fix the failing test you need to use *slice* instead of *splice*

So the code of the test will look like:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var result = arr.slice(2, 3);
assertEquals([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], arr);
```

If you would like to have some custom message when this assert fails you can write it as a first argument:

```
assertEquals("message text", [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], arr);
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Please, could you correct me if I'am wrong:
Q: I would like to know if it's possible to fix that failure exception.
A: Yes, sure it is possible.

Should I provide some sample of code?